Does this sentence sound natural to Natives?
Does this sentence sound natural to natives?
Please help me from South Korea, L2-learner

Albert Einstein stated that he would not have lent his ______ to the cause of the proponents of building the atomic bomb if he had known in advance that the Germans would not develop one.

The supposed answer is empathy. And the other answers are below.

conscience
credibility
fame
decree

This is Korean version of GRE. and I need your help.
In my experience, I think I have seen this question before and I suggest that the answer would be empathy.
But these days, this question has been bandied across the students. I need your own answer.

The only answers above that make sense are

lent his credibility,

and

lent his fame.

The expressions "lent his credibility" and "lent his fame" are both used in English, and make some sense in this context. See Ngram.
Nobody says "lent his empathy" in English, and I don't see how that makes sense. Both credibility and fame are attributes that could help Einstein encourage the building of the atomic bomb. However, I don't see how the trait empathy could be used for this.
